# AngularJS: Pass functions and variables to directive's

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have one situation where I have to pass the directive, functions and variables declared in the controller. I can easily do this with $scope. But I read one article which states that we should not populate the scope instead use this. The article had the following example -

```
//Don't do this
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.name = 'Techno Fattie';
});

//Do this
var MyCtrl = function(){
   this.name = 'Techno Fattie';
};

app.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

I liked the idea and I tried implementing the same in my situation which is as follows -

I have a CountryController - which I modified to use this instead of $scope.
I have a countryList.tpl.html - which has only a directive in it and no other code.

Now I have a parent controller which has a stateProvider where I have configuration for country. something like this -

```
  .state('app.country', {
  url: "/country",
  templateUrl: "countryList.tpl.html",
  controller: CountryController 
})
```

I converted the controller's $scope to this but then I observed that I the directive is not receiving the function and variables and the page is not loading properly.

Is it that if the tpl file has a directive then this approach is not useful? If that is not true, then how can we do this? Can anyone help?

Comment: where is the directive here? can you give plnkr/fiddle

Comment: you have to somewhere tell that it is a "controllerAs" controller. Show us more code (html + directive).